# Efficient usage of memory with large data size

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, memory, optimization

I am performing a plot as below:

```
for i in range(len(classederror)):
    plt.scatter(xlag, classederror[i, :])
plt.show()
```

with the sizes of the variables being:

```
xlag = np.array(2, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250)

xlag.size = (11,)
```

- `classederror` = 176501 rows x 11 columns

However, I get memory problem and it is due to the large size of `classederror`.

Is there a pythonic/more efficient way of doing this without having problem with memory?

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO DO**

As seen in the image below, the x-axis is `xlag` and the y-axis is `classederror`

I want to plot each row in `classederror` for a range of x-axis values and study the distribution of the data and finally i Should obtain something similar to image below.

[image]

Comment: `classederror` is tiny. Assuming a 64-bit numeric type, e.g. np.float64, this would be roughly (176501* 11 * 8 * 1e-6) = 15.53 megabytes... Now, I don't know a lot about the internals of `matplotlib`, but even if it were creating copies underneath the hood, I don't see this causing a memory issue. But someone more familiar might be able to comment.

Comment: So a rough test on my computer using a `(10000, 11)` shaped array, I'm consuming something like 300 megabytes (the whole process). Assuming this memory usage grows linearly, then that would explain your problem. It isn't surprising that trying to plot 176501 lines might cause this error... what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The code as it currently is produces 176501 individual lines; one `Line2D` object on a plot for sure costs much more than 8 bytes.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest for sure, I was merely pointing out that the array itself shouldn't be a problem. I'm not sure if there's a way around this using matplotlib.

Comment: Exactly: "what exactly are you trying to do?" I guess if I knew the purpose of this I could give a solution which creates a lot less objects. Just as an example, an image with 420 x 420 = 176400 pixels takes only a fraction of that memory - the reason is that it is a single object which is drawn.

Comment: Does it work if you plot every nth line?

Comment: I have edited the original question to make it a bit clearer. It works without problem when the classederror is smaller in size. So I have a large set of data and what i have done in classederror is to group the data into 11 columns(classes) whereby each column represent data that certify a specific condition. So my plot should finially look like the image represented in the question

Comment: Now I'm lost. The image shows 11 lines, yet you try to plot 170000 lines? What are the values in `xlag`? Can you create a [mcve] of the issue (if you want, just use 4 rows, instead of 170000)?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, the image shows 11 'lines' but they are not actaully lines, since each 'line' is a set of point (i.e each line is made up of 176501 points).

Comment: There are no points in the code, just lines. Hence the code you show would anyway not produce the shown output. That is why I asked you for a [mcve] and an explanation of the data inside `xlag`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, I have changed the image for a much clearer one. They are a lots of points (actually they look like lines because i'm using plot and not scatter function)

Comment: Are you willingly irgnoring my comments? In that case the answer is simply: It doesn't make sense to plot 170000 points if the aim is to see 11 lines.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, Each x-axis value has a set of points (176501) and I have 11 x-values. And that is why the points are grouped into 11 lines/classes. For exampl, for the first x-axis value, the y-axis values (176501 points) ranges between -0.2 and 0.2 and for the last x-axis values the y-axis value ranges between -30 and 45. Unless I am not understanding your question, i do not know how i am ignoring your comment.

Comment: They are not points, they are **lines**. That is what you aren't understanding. Anyway, it seems like what you really want is 11 box blots or violin plots or something. 176501 lines is just not going to be efficient in matplotlib

Comment: Ok, I want to have a [mcve]. If that is too much for you, at least print out `xlag` as well as `xlag.shape`. Next copy the exact `plot`-line from your code, since the codeline you show in the question *cannot* produce the plot shown. Those are 3 pieces of information - once I have them I'm happy to pursue this further, else I am not.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, 

xlag = np.array(2, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250)

xlag.size = (11,) 
classederror.size = (176501, 11) 

and for the image in the question, i used the following code 

for i in range(len(classederror)):
    plt.scatter(xlag, classederror[i, :])
plt.show()

I have updated it in the question though.

Comment: Ok, sorry, who would have guessed that *"i'm using plot and not scatter function"* actually means that you *are* using scatter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is of course much more efficient to plot a single scatter plot than 176501 scatter plots.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xlag = np.array([2, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250])
classederror = (np.random.randn(176501, 11)*25)*(0.2+np.sort(np.random.rand(11)))

plt.scatter(np.tile(xlag,len(classederror)), classederror.flatten())

plt.show()
```

[image]

Given the limited information one can draw from such a plot, it may make sense to directly plot 11 lines.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xlag = np.array([2, 25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250])
classederror = (np.random.randn(176501, 11)*25)*(0.2+np.sort(np.random.rand(11)))

vals = np.c_[classederror.min(axis=0),classederror.max(axis=0)].T
x= np.c_[xlag,xlag].T
plt.plot(x,vals, color="C0", lw=2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

To obtain information about the density of points, one may use other means, e.g. a violin plot.

```
plt.violinplot(classederror, xlag, points=50, widths=20,
                  showmeans=True, showextrema=True, showmedians=True)
```

[image]

Comment: You make really beautiful illustrations :)